# Через какие координаты проходит отрезок

Tags: 3d

На вход подаётся две координаты a(x,y,z) и b(x¹,y¹,z¹). Нужно узнать координаты всех кубов через которые проходит отрезок ab.

Comment: Что имеется в виду под словом "кубов" в данном контексте и откуда эти "кубы" брать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вопрос сложный раздели его на несколько простых:

1. кубы делим на квадраты.
2. квадраты делим на треугольники.
3. по формуле определяем пересечение треугольника и отрезка
   https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1771521.html

Если есть пересечение хоть с одним треугольником куба, значит отрезок вошел в куб.
Если пересечений два значит отрезок проходит насквозь.

Comment: Если отрезок находится полностью внутри куба, то пересечений с его треугольниками не будет

Comment: тогда дополнительно проверим обе точки на ее вхождение в куб, и готово.